# pandas df to python nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Assume I have `df` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [1, 2],
    'C': [3, 4]
})
```

How can I turn this into a nested `dict` of the format:

```
{'a': {'B': 1, 'C': 2}, 'b': {'B': 3, 'C': 4}}
```

I've tried `df.to_dict()` which doesn't return the format I'm after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `set_index`

```
df.set_index('A').to_dict('index')
Out[8]: {'a': {'B': 1, 'C': 3}, 'b': {'B': 2, 'C': 4}}
```

Comment: This is like watching a gun fight in those old spaghetti westerns.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `A` as index and use `to_dict`:

```
df.set_index('A').to_dict('i')
# {'a': {'B': 1, 'C': 3}, 'b': {'B': 2, 'C': 4}}
```